# Multiple Instance Arguments

Tags: c#

Good day!
I'm wondering if it's possible to assign multiple different types of arguments when instantiating a class.

Here's an example of what I have right now

```
    public Unit(Vector2 Position, Color col)
    {
        this.position = Position;
        this.color = col;
    }
```

Notice how it needs both a Vec2 & Color, I'm wondering if it's possible to do it so I can choose between either ONLY one argument or both example follows below.

## 1

```
    public Unit(Vector2 Position)
    {
        this.position = Position;
        this.color = Color.White;
    }
```

## 2

```
    public Unit(Vector2 Position, Color col)
    {
        this.position = Position;
        this.color = col;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just write both methods? I mean write option 1 and then below write option 2. Then it's your choice how you make the instance of the class (either 1 or 2 arguments).

Comment: Yes that works, I was thinking more if there was a way that doesn't need this wall of code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can overload constructors exactly like that. I would suggest making one overload call the other though:

```
public Unit(Vector2 position) : this(position, Color.White)
{
}

public Unit(Vector2 position, Color col)
{
    this.position = position;
    this.color = col;
}
```

Comment: It should be: `public Unit(...) : this(...) { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, if you are using C# 4 or newer, is default values

```
public Unit(Vector2 position, Color col = Color.White)
{
    this.position = position;
    this.color = col;
}


Unit u = new Unit(myVector2);  // defaults to white
Unit u2 = new Unit(myVector2, Color.Blue);
```

Comment: That snippet alone, no, as it's not a full class. But if you are using C#4 or greater, then yes the above generally works.